# Problema con AWS y PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, aws

Estoy tratando de enviar correos con PHPMailer y A.W.S (usando el servicio S.E.S); cuando uso los parámetros de SMTP de google funciona bien; cuando coloco las credenciales de amazon, me deja de funcionar.

```
<?php

include_once('conexion.php');
include_once('utilidades.php');

var_dump($_SESSION['loggedin']); 
var_dump($_SESSION['userid']);
var_dump($_SESSION['username']);
$padecimiento ="";
$nombreUsuario = $_SESSION['name'];

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer();


$fechaRegistro = date('Y/m/j');
$con = new oRG_BDConector('localhost','root','','nombre de bdd');
$con->oConectar();



$selecCorreo = $con->oEjecutar("SELECT email FROM usuario WHERE id = {$idusuario}");
$count = 0;

while($row = $con->oDatosObjeto($selecCorreo)){
    //debug($row);WHERE nom_usuario = '$username '
    //var_dump($row);
    $count++;
    $result = $row;
}
$resultEmail = $result->email;




    //Envio del correo



    $sender = 'correo que envia mails pero es una cuenta gmail';
    $senderName = 'Nombre';
    $recipient = $resultEmail;
    $usernameSmtp = 'user de amazon';
    $passwordSmtp = 'pass de user';
    $host = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com';
    $port = 587;
    $subject =  'Resultados del proceso indagatorio de: '.$nombreUsuario ;
    $bodyText =  'prueba';
    $BodyHTML =  '<h2>Proceso indagatorio</h2>
    <p>'.$saludo.' '.$nombreUsuario.' tienes '.$padecimiento.' </p>';

    //SMTP Settings
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = $host; //host
    $mail->Port = $port; //puerto
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // hablitiamos autenticacion smtp
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; //protoccolo de criptografia
    $mail->Username = $usernameSmtp;  //cuenta que se va a encargar de envio y uso de protocolo
    $mail->Password = $passwordSmtp; //cuenta
    //Email Settings
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    //QUIEN ENVIA
    $mail->setFrom($sender, $senderName);//quien envia
    //QUIEN RECIBE
    $mail->addAddress = $recipient;// destinatario

    //FORMATO DE CORREO
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->Body       = $BodyHTML;
    $mail->AltBody    = $bodyText;

    if ($mail->send()) {
        $status = "success";
        $response = "se envió!!";
    } else {
        $status = "failed";
        $response = "Algo salió mal: <br><br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

    //header('Location: index.php');
    echo "<br />" . "<h1>" . "Gracias por registrarse!" . "</h1>";
    echo "<h3>" . "Bienvenido: " .$_SESSION['username']. "</h3>" . "\n\n";
    echo "<h3>" . "Iniciar Sesion: " . "<a href='login.html'>Login</a>" . "</h3>"; 
}else{
    //echo "Error al crear el usuario." . $query . "<br>" . $conexion->error; 
}

}
?>
```

Quité de la pregunta todas mis variables para acortar el código, pero están perfectas; de hecho, no me da ningún error cuando se supone que envía el correo, pero este nunca llega y en mi consola de aws no se refleja el envió.

No estoy seguro si para el correo que envía pueda usar una cuenta gmail o tiene que ser con el dominio que tengo alojado en aws, de verdad ya no se que pueda ser.

Comment: Las credenciales de SES de un usuario **no son las mismas** que las credenciales de autenticación de dicho usuario... es decir, SES genera un usuario y contraseña diferentes ... esto lo has tenido en cuenta?

Comment: @eferion creo que si (lo tuve en cuenta, pero, no estoy seguro, sy nuevo usando aws y sus herramientas ) , yo puse las credenciales de smtp que me da la consola ( cuando las genero ) en estas variables "$usernameSmtp " y "$passwordSmtp" ... acabo de intentar colocando en mi viariable $sender un correo con amazon pero tampoco envía

Comment: Podrias probar la conexion desde el shell del server hacia la interfaz SMTP de Amazon SES. Aqui te explica como hacerlo: [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp-client-command-line.html)

Comment: echa un vistazo a los logs en CloudWatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-retrieving-cloudwatch.html